# How to remove separators from SwiftUI list in WatchOS?

Tags: swift, swiftui, watchos

How can I remove separators from SwiftUI list in WatchOS?

I have gone through some answers in stackoverflow, they suggest to use

```swift
UITableView.appearance().tableFooterView = UIView()
UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none
```

Looks like they only work for iOS and apparently they don't work for WatchOS SwiftUI list. Is there any way to customize it?

Edit -

```swift
UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none
```

Apparently the above code doesn't hide the separators in iOS 14.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you mean by separator on WatchOS List, but probably you just need to set platter color as below for first row

[image]

```
var body: some View {
    List {
        Text("Hello, World!").listRowPlatterColor(Color.black)
        Text("Hello, World!")
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}
```

Comment: It removes the background color. Still there is separator space between two cells. I need to remove them. What I have done is used edgesinset for the cell and have given a negative value for the top inset, but I am not sure if it is the right way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [listRowBackground()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/color/3265493-listrowbackground) as Paul Hudson shows on [Hacking with Swift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-set-the-background-color-of-list-rows-using-listrowbackground)

```
List {
    ForEach(0..<10) {
        Text("Row \($0)")
    }
    .listRowBackground(Color.red)
}
```

**Edit** to highlight the comment:

There's no API for modifying the `List` item spacing  at present. You'd either have to create a custom `ListStyle`, or not use a `List`.
If you use a `ScrollView` with a `VStack` you'll be able to get similar results. In this case you can set the `spacing` on the `VStack` to achieve the results you want.

Comment: But, what about the spacing between the cells. There seems to be a default space between the cells. I don’t want it though.

Comment: There's no API for modifying this at present. You'd either have to create a custom ListStyle, or not use a List. If you use a ScrollView with a VStack you'll be able to get similar results.

Comment: For reference `WatchKit`'s equivalent for `UITableView` is `WKInterfaceTable` but as you've seen the Appearance proxy API `UIAppearance` doesn't exist on `WatchOS`.

Comment: Yes as @Tristan had specified, using ScrollView with a VStack is the only efficient way of achieving this.